# XHR file upload fails only from my IE 11 installation

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I even totally reset my IE 11 install, yet an XHR file upload is failing with a permissions failure from the server (HTTP error at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionsChecks). Chrome and Firefox both succeed. Interestingly, others in my group can upload successfully using IE 11. Now why would only my install be problematic? Feeling stumped ...

Comment: This entirely depends on what the code is doing on the server.  Do you have access to that code, and/or stack trace information?

Comment: Just doing due diligence before involving server admins. Right now investigating if Windows file permissions might be involved somehow

Comment: so it's actually my machine somehow. IE 11 file upload succeeds from a different PC. Now to sleuth why my machine's different ...

Comment: Can you share the detailed error message? According to your description, I suggest you check your IE browser Security zones setting (compare with other PC which could successfully upload the files) and try to add Trusted sites.